# Rails 3.1 - in routes.rb, using the wildcard, match '*' is not catching any routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, routes, wildcard

In my `pages_controller.rb` file I have a `not_found` action. I want to have any route that is not matched by an entry in my `routes.rb` file to go to `pages#not_found`.  Wanting to leverage a wildcard, I made this the last line of my routes.rb file:

```
match '*' => 'pages#not_found'
```

I'm basing this on what I read about wildcards in the ruby guide for routing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.0/routing.html).  However it is not working.  Instead of going to `pages#not_found`, I get: `AcctionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "*"` (which is unfortunately caught by ActionDispatch so I don't have a way to handle the exception.)

Troubleshooting, I put this in my routes.rb file:

```
match 'foobar' => 'pages#not_found'
```

the not_found action was executed on `http://localhost:3000/foobar` as expected.  I tried a partial wild card:

```
match 'foo*' => 'pages#not_found'
```

According to the Rails guide, this should match to http://localhost:3000/foobar but it doesn't.  Is there something special that you need to do to get wildcards to work in routes?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this :

```
match '*path' => 'pages#not_found'
```