# Rails Routing: How to route to a specific controller/action/id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I think this should be a simple question. I would like to route a URL of the form:

```
http://mywebsite.com/my_special_tag
```

to a specific controller/action pair with a specific id, e.g.

```
http://mywebsite.com/user/post/13
```

(where 13 is the id I want to pass into the controller/action).

Note also that I don't want to redirect, just want to render.

Is there an easy way to do this in Rails 3?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the status of this? Have you found a solution to this problem? If so, it'd be helpful if you posted the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your know specifically which URL you want to have rendered to, you can explicitly match to the target in your routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'my_special_tag' => 'user#post', :defaults => {:id => 13}
```

Note that this necessarily requires that you have a `post` action within a `UserController` (note that the names are *singular*, as they are in your desired path).

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. Gives me an error "uninitialized constant User".

Why is that?

Comment: Can you verify that your path is indeed `user/post/13`, and not `users/posts/13` (or some iteration of that)?

Comment: It still didn't work. But here's what did:

get 'my_special_tag', :controller => 'user', :action => 'post', :id => '13'

Not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a table like this:

tags table:

```
id | post_id | tag
-------------------
1  |    13   | my_special_tag
```

And then you need a `before_filter`, that takes that tag and checks the database for the post_id.

You'd also need a wildcard route that looks something like this: [Rails 3.1 - in routes.rb, using the wildcard, match '*' is not catching any routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380805/rails-3-1-in-routes-rb-using-the-wildcard-match-is-not-catching-any-rout)

Start with that and then let us know when you have more specific questions and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your routes you should get the syntax for a user post route, if you have defined the nested route correctly.

To alias the route, you can define a specific id for a particular match like so:

```
match '/special_tag' => 'posts#index', :defaults => { :id => '5' }
```

**Update**

To clarify, the above should only be used for a couple of specific pages you'd like to alias a route for. If you want to provide a more user friendly link to each user post page, I'd recommend something like https://github.com/norman/friendly_id which allows you to have routes like

```
http://example.com/states/washington
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/states/4323454
```